# hostapd.service not found

Tags: pi-2, wifi, server

I am trying to make a Raspberry Pi 2 as a wifi access point in a standalone network.

I followed this tutorial: https://docs.google.com/document/d/16hJS7fnPyKUwbvR33_nMku_b6XcYaBJXVpeCIMoJzcQ/pub

At one point in the tutorial it teaches how to download a hostapd that works in particular with Edimax wifi dongles. I have bought one for this project.

These are the commands I followed to install the hostapd:

```
sudo wget https://github.com/jenssegers/RTL8188-hostapd/archive/v2.0.tar.gz
tar -zxvf v2.0.tar.gz
cd RTL8188-hostapd-2.0/hostapd
sudo make install
sudo service hostapd restart
```

Everything was working perfectly fine except when I got to the last command. The cmd prompt was returning "hostapd.service not found"
I don't understand what is wrong. I repeated this process multiple times, and every time I got the same error message.

Any help is appreciated. :)

Comment: Does the tutorial recommend to install from sources? Cause you might try installing from packages.... and then the systemd file for it is included (so you can start it with systemctl).

Comment: And the fact that it's X-brand doesn't make a difference (I would assume) given that hostapd probably is not in charge of having its own drivers for different pieces of hardware. It would be the kernel that takes care of that and so hostapd would be agnostic to whatever piece of hardware it is (again, it's my _educated_ guess).

Comment: the fact that the source code inside that tar file is over 3 years old is probably the issue

Comment: after clean install, you probably only need `apt-get install firmware-realtek hostapd` then configure `/etc/hostapd.conf`

Comment: Thanks, for your answers. I'll try to implement what both of you have said.